# Unexpected URL when POSTing from a nested resource

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We have ember.js resources and routes setup to GET users from within an org with URLs that look like /orgs/`<org-id>`/users. Note: Both the ember URLs and the API URLs use this convention.

When we get an org, ember data does a GET using the URL /orgs/`<org-id>` and the returned JSON includes links that tell it to get users from the URL /orgs/`<org-id>`/users. All goes well with getting the users for any given org.

When we go to post a new user we find that ember data POSTs to the URL /users which is not what we expect. Instead, we expect ember data to post to the same place that we got the users (the URL /orgs/`<org-id>`/users).

Do we need to write custom code to make this happen or are we missing something in the way we are working with ember data (i.e. the returned JSON, the route configuration, etc.)?

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('orgs', function () {
    this.resource('org', { path : ':org-id' }, function () {
      this.resource('users', function () {
        this.resource('user, { path : ':user-id' }, function () {
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

GET for /orgs returns the following JSON

```
{"orgs":[{"org_name":"Test Org","id":10001,"links":{"users":"/orgs/10001/users"}}]}
```

GET for /orgs/`<org-id>` returns the following JSON

```
{"org":{"org_name":"Test Org","id":10001,"links":{"users":"/orgs/10001/users"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That currently seems to be the default behaviour for async relationships.

What I might look at doing in this situation is to subclass your User model something like this:

```
User = DS.Model.extend ... # keep as is
Organization = DS.Model.extend
  orgName: DS.attr('string')
  users: DS.hasMany('organizationUser') # instead of DS.hasMany('user')

OrganizationUser = User.extend()

OrganizationUserAdapter = ApplicationAdapter.extend
  buildURL: (type, id) ->
    # You'll need to do some mangling here to get the record's organizationId
    # (perhaps by passing it from wherever `this.ajax(this.buildURL( ...`
    # is called in your adapter

OrganizationUserSerializer = ApplicationSerializer.extend
  serializeIntoHash: (hash, type, record, options) ->
    hash['user'] = @serialize(record, options) # Use 'user' as root instead of 'organizationUser'
```

There may be some other defaults you'd need to override in your adapters and serializers, but I've had some success doing something similar to this in the past.

EDIT: A simpler way might be just to stick with your regular User model and overwrite the `createRecord`, `updateRecord`, and `deleteRecord` methods in your UserAdapter to use the expected URL.

Comment: Based on your ideas above it appears there are 3 choices:  
1. Modify buildurl.  
2. Modify createRecord, updateRecord, deleteRecord like in [link]  (https://github.com/twalpole/data/commit/239ad99127bacdacb11886654990c52275bca64c)  
3. Consider what we want to do as an anti-pattern as mentioned in [link](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/i-was-being-silly-to-fight-ember-data-on-nested-urls-i-think/2082).  
Would you recommend #2 above?

Comment: Apologies for the confusing answer. I'd start out with #2 - you'd probably get a fair amount of mileage out of it before running into any problems.